# Ajax to Curl form submission

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I have an ajax that submits form data with file to a controller, the controller will send this form data to my api using curl. How can I do that?

I cannot directly submit the form to my api, it have to go through my controller. :(

my ajax

```
data = new FormData();
        data.append( 'file', $( '#file' )[0].files[0] );
        data.append( 'title', title );
        data.append( 'description', description );
        data.append( 'module_id', module_id );
        data.append( 'tags', tags );
        data.append( 'groups', groups );
        $.ajax({
            url: '/controller/upload',
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function ( data ) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
```

My controller function

```
public function uploadAction(){
    $response = new \Phalcon\Http\Response();
    $response->setContentType('application/json', 'UTF-8');
    $response2 = "{}";
    if($this->request->getPost()){
        $version = $this->session->get("version");
        $data = $this->request->getPost('data');
        $response2 = $this->useCurl("api_link","POST",$data);
    }
    return $response->setContent($response2);
}
```

Comment: What does `$this->useCurl ` do ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `url: '/controller/upload'` should be `url: '/controller/uploadAction',`  since you are calling the `uploadAction`method inside `controller`.

using cURL:

```
function useCurl($api_link, $data){
            $ch = curl_init($api_link);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

            $ret = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $ret; 
}
```

in your ajax `success` callback:

```
success: function ( data ) {
            //do something with data from uploadAction method  (e.g console.log)
          console.log(data);
        }
```